# Installing luasql-mysql in Windows 10: cannot find -lmysqlclient

Tags: mysql, lua, luarocks

I try to install luasql-mysql with luarocks (Lua 5.3.5, LuaRocks 3.0.3). I have Mysql Connector C 6.1 installed in directory "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1". I have MinGW installed in C:\TDM-GCC-64 dir.

When I run command

```
luarocks --from=http://rocks.luarocks.org/dev install luasql-mysql cvs-1 MYSQL_INCDIR="C:\mysql-5.7.23-winx64\include" MYSQL_LIBDIR="C:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector C++ 8.0\lib64"
```

I get the error

```
Cloning into 'luasql'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 122, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (122/122), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (92/92), done.
remote: Total 122 (delta 46), reused 55 (delta 16), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (122/122), 94.79 KiB | 197.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (46/46), done.
C:\TDM-GCC-64\bin\gcc.exe -O2 -c -o src/luasql.o -IC:\lua\include src/luasql.c -IC:\mysql-5.7.23-winx64\include
C:\TDM-GCC-64\bin\gcc.exe -O2 -c -o src/ls_mysql.o -IC:\lua\include src/ls_mysql.c -IC:\mysql-5.7.23-winx64\include
C:\TDM-GCC-64\bin\gcc.exe -shared -o luasql/mysql.dll src/luasql.o src/ls_mysql.o -LC:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector C++ 8.0\lib64 -lmysqlclient C:\lua\bin/lua53.dll -lm
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmysqlclient
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How to specify paths correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I could find workaround solution. Here is steps to make Lua 5.1 running in Windows 10 x64 Pro connect to Mysql server:

1. Get the latest Lua 5.1 from https://code.google.com/archive/p/luaforwindows/downloads
2. Install it. I have to remove all previous Lua and LuaRocks installations in my workstation
3. Added environment variable LUA_CPATH  with value:

   C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\clibs\?.dll;C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\clibs\luasql\?.dll
4. Run mysql lua script in NEW cmd